# Glide throwing 'java.lang.SecurityException' while loading profile picture URL from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-glide, storage-access-framework

I am getting following error message while loading profile picture of a firebase user from **firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()** method (Note: Im using **Glide** to load picture from URI).

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{ccece88 5351:joseph.benton.viqua/u0a122} (pid=5351, uid=10122) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I checked the return vale of firebase.getPhotoUrl() method and its vale is

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A10337

This is my code snippet

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if(user!=null){
            try {
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                        .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_white_48dp)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                .skipMemoryCache(true))
                        .into(imgAccount);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: Did you allow your security in Firebase? The rules at the console

Comment: Hi Zuhrain, in which section I have to change rule ? Authentication?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database . Did you allow the rules?

Comment: this is the current rule in real time database

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != true",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: I think you can refer to this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: Thanks  Zuhrain. But the issue was related to the profile picture upload module. I have updated the reason in answer part. But i'm still wondering how getPhotoUrl() given me reference to some image file even if the upload was not proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm able to find the issue, the issue was related to the profile picture upload module. The uploading module was selecting wrong file type. Uploaded proper image file and above code is working fine as expected.